# How can i check KendoTreeview has Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

How can i expand kendotreeView nodes with no children?, i need help checking if parent has child node if there is one or more child i want to keep it collapsed otherwise expanded.

I used the following Jquery code and works fine but it find by text value.  i rather check all node with child li and expand if no child exist.

```
        var treeview;
        treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
        var nodeToExpand = treeview.findByText('abc.'); 
        treeview.expand(nodeToExpand);
```

is there anyways to replace the code above to collapse or expand based on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all nodes, and if any do not have children nodes, expand them like this:

```
var treeView = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var nodes = treeView.dataSource.view();

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (!nodes[i].hasChildren) {
        treeView.expand(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi G_P,  list doesn't have li but shown me hasChildren :true

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean - Perhaps add to the end of your question with your current full treeview code and example data for what the issue is?